# Actionscript error

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a flex application which is configured with blazeds sever and i am pulling images from remote database from my flex application, but as soon as i click the get image button to pull images it is giving some action script error.
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter bytes must be non-null.
    at flash.display::Loader/_loadBytes()
    at flash.display::Loader/loadBytes()

I tried googling but couldn't found any solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: show the code for your call please.

Comment: No code = no way to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You everyone it was a my code error, it give this error if no value is returned to load bytes . I was pulling a image from a table where no image was present and therefore returning null value in load bytes.

Comment: Please mark either your or Glenn's answer as the accepted answer so the question doesn't remained "unanswered" in the system.

Answer (score 0):

You have a null parameter inside the function `flash.display::Loader/loadBytes()`. ;)

Short answer is that you're probably fetching the wrong url. Use firebug or Fiddler or something to determine whether the url is correct. If that's not the case, maybe you're not handling the right events.

Like the comments say, we need the code.